# I have one Card Widget that I use in different GridView.builder. How can I do that depending on where it was clicked the onTap function changes?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have one Card Widget that I use in different GridView.builder. How can I do that depending on where it was clicked the onTap function changes?

I saw that maybe I could use a Key, if so, how could I implement this?

Comment: are you trying to say, if you click on the card in the gridview.builder you want to perform another function ?

Comment: Yes. I am using the same card widget on different pages.  but according to the page being used, I would like the onTap function to perform another function.  I would like to avoid creating a Card (which is the same) for each page that will be used.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the card with GestureDetector the pass in the function like this

```
class Card extend stat.....{
final Function tap;
// the constructor here 
Card({this.tap}):super()
@ovaride
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GestureDetector(
ontap: tap,
child: Card(....)
);

}
```

then call it

```
Card(
tap:(){

//your function here
}
)
```